# How to pass and return 3d array to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created a 3d array into main function because one of its size came from used input. I am using C++

```
 std::cin >> size;
    typedef int T[8][3]; 
    T* tables = new T[size];
```

It is basically `tables[size][8][3]`
Now I have to use this 3d table in different functions and have to store values into it. The best way to do it by make this table as a global variable. But I am not sure that I can do it after main function. The other option I have, that I have to pass this table as a parameter and have to return that at the end of the function. 
I have tried both the approach but I am having error. Please help me about this issue. I don't know which approach to choose and how to do it.
Thank you in advance.

**Example:**This an example what I really want to do. Here I create a 3d array in main function and through another function I gave some input into that array and again print that in main function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;


class M
{
public:
    int i,j,k;
public:
    int pass(int (*table)[8][3],int size);

}


int M:: pass(int (*table)[8][3],int s)
{
for (i=0;i<s;i++)
  {
      //int a = tables[i][2][1];
      for(j=0;j<8;j++)
      {
          for(k=0;k<3;k++)
          {
              table[i][j][k]=i;

          }
      }


  }

return (*table)[8][3]; // not sure about this

}



int main()
{
  int size,i,j,k;


  std::cin >> size;

 typedef int T[8][3]; // T is your 2d array type

T* tables = new T[size];
cout << "test";


M mx;
mx.pass(tables,size); // not sure


for (i=0;i<size;i++)
  {

      for(j=0;j<8;j++)
      {
          for(k=0;k<3;k++)
          {
              cout<<tables[i][j][k];
              cout<<"   ";

          }
          cout<<endl;
      }

      cout<<endl;
      cout<<"..........." << i <<endl;
  }

getch();

}
```

Comment: Posting example code and the relevant compiler error messages will go a long way in getting some useful feedback.

Comment: "Now I have to use this 3d table in different functions and have to store values into it. The best way to do it by make this table as a global variable." No, you can make a class that keeps the 3d table private, and use the functions in the public section of the class.

Comment: Also, please post your main program. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I completely understand your problem. But you can definitely store the pointer locally in your object and reference it elsewhere. Something like this:

```
class M
{
public:
    M(int(*tbl)[8][3]) : table(tbl) { }
    int(*table)[8][3];
    int i, j, k;
public:
    void pass(int size);

};

void M::pass(int s)
{
    for (i = 0; i<s; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<8; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k<3; k++)
            {
                table[i][j][k] = i;

            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size, i, j, k;
    std::cin >> size;
    typedef int T[8][3]; // T is your 2d array type
    T* tables = new T[size];
    cout << "test";
    M mx(tables);
    mx.pass(size); // not sure
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<8; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k<3; k++)
            {
                cout << tables[i][j][k];
                // or you can also:
                // cout << mx.table[i][j][k];
                cout << "   ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "..........." << i << endl;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: This code is working. but could please explain these 2 lines.   M(int(*tbl)[8][3]) : table(tbl) { }  AND M mx(tables);

Comment: "M(int(*tbl)[8][3]) : table(tbl) { }"

Comment: The first one is the constructor, which will add the pointer to the object. Sorry, I used a bit obtuse syntax. It is basically a constructor with this->table = tbl (the constructor parameter). The second line is calling the constructor with the table as a parameter in order to create the object with that property on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a dynamic 3D array whose two dimensions are fixed, Use a `std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 8>` as your 2D array. Use a `std::vector<__2D_ARRAY_TYPE>` to create the 3D array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 8> array_2d ;
    std::vector<decltype(array_2d)> array_3d ;
    int size = 4 ;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
                array_2d[j][k] = j + k ;
        array_3d.push_back(array_2d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Something like this you can use easily which does the job more easily without any manual memory management.

You can pass it to a function. The signature would be :

```
return_type function_name(const std::vector<std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 8>>& array_3d)
{ .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
class M
{
public:
    int i,j,k;
public:
    int pass(int (*table)[8][3],int size);

}
```

you don't have to write public twice. You can simply put all of the public member data under the keyword `public`.

Also, you seem to be re-writing your function over again at the very end. Instead of

`cout<<tables[i][j][k];`

You can write

`cout<<*tables`